# Extract a specific JSON structure from a json string in a Spark Rdd - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a json string such as:

```
{"sequence":89,"id":8697344444103393,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527636408955},1],
{"sequence":155,"id":8697389381205360,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527637858607},1],
{"sequence":136,"id":8697374208897843,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527637405129},1],
{"sequence":189,"id":8697413135394406,"trackingInfo":{"row":0,"trackId":14272744,"requestId":"284929d9-6147-4924-a19f-4a308730354c-3348447","rank":0,"videoId":80075830,"location":"PostPlay\/Next"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527638558756},1],
{"sequence":130,"id":8697373887446384,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527637394083}]
```

What would be the best approach here ? Ive tired

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonString)).flatMap(_.split("}"))
val trackingRdd = rdd.filter(_.contains("trackingInfo"))
```

An example output of this attempt is :

```
,{"sequence":89,"id":8697344444103393,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"
```

As you can see I nearlly have all the data I want except `"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527636408955},1]` as I split on }

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read data with JSON structure, for example:

```
scala> val df=spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonString))).select(explode(col("reverseDeltas"))).select(explode(col("col"))).map(_.getString(0)).filter(_.indexOf('{')>=0)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> spark.read.json(df).filter(col("trackingInfo").isNotNull).select("trackingInfo").toJSON.show(false)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"trackingInfo":{"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","location":"Browse","rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"videoId":80000778}}|
|{"trackingInfo":{"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","location":"Browse","rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"videoId":80000778}}|
|{"trackingInfo":{"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","location":"Browse","rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"videoId":80000778}}|
|{"trackingInfo":{"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","location":"Browse","rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"videoId":80000778}}|
|{"trackingInfo":{"location":"PostPlay/Next","rank":0,"requestId":"284929d9-6147-4924-a19f-4a308730354c-3348447","row":0,"trackId":14272744,"videoId":80075830}}                                                                  |
|{"trackingInfo":{"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","location":"Browse","rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"videoId":80000778}}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Would it be possible to get the outer values around that record which has trackingInfo ? So I need `sequence`, `id`, `type` (just the first element) and `time`

Comment: actually I can get those by doing a simple filter after doing your first line and keeping it an rdd. And the doing `df.filter(_.contains("trackingInfo"))`. An example result record looks like ; 
`{"sequence":89,"id":8697344444103393,"trackingInfo":{"location":"Browse","row":0,"trackId":14170286,"listId":"cd7c2c7a-00f6-4035-867f-d1dd7d89972d_6625365X3XX1505943605585","videoId":80000778,"rank":0,"requestId":"ac12f4e1-5644-46af-87d1-ec3b92ce4896-4071171"},"type":["Play","Action","Session"],"time":527636408955}`

Comment: would you mind explain the first line of your code ? `sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonString)))
  .select(explode(col("reverseDeltas")))
  .select(explode(col("col")))
  .map(_.getString(0))
  .filter(_.indexOf('{') >= 0)`

Comment: After JSON data loaded as DataSet, we can use Spark SQL to query it using some SQL functions. FYI:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-