# Extract a Json from an array inside a json in spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a complicated JSON column whose structure is :

> story{
>   cards: [{story-elements: [{...}{...}{...}}]}

The length of the story-elements is variable. I need to extract a particular JSON block from the story-elements array. For this, I first need to extract the story-elements.

Here is the code which I have tried, but it is giving error:

```
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, MappingException}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def getJsonContent(jsonstring: String): (String) = {
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val parsedJson = parse(jsonstring)
val value1 = (parsedJson\"cards"\"story-elements").extract[String]
value1
}
val getJsonContentUDF = udf((jsonstring: String) => 
getJsonContent(jsonstring))

input.withColumn("cards",getJsonContentUDF(input("storyDataFrame")))
```

Comment: Can u post the whole JSON?

Comment: {
story: {
cards: [
{
story-elements: [
{
description: "",
page-url: "/story/03d952fb-83f9-468e-a02c-fe6e2431fa6c/element/fa52a7d9-1d02-4214-b7ab-e86c8c635403",
type: "text",
family-id: "22f2d777-d51e-435a-a4d8-ba47f0b9e257",
title: "",
id: "fa52a7d9-1d02-4214-b7ab-e86c8c635403",
metadata: { },
subtype: null,
text: "<p>The tragic death of the two Kannada actors Raghava Uday and Anil on Monday</p>"
}
]}
]
}

Comment: Put that in question also

Comment: And have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46833649/7124761

Comment: The link doesn't serve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

According to json you provided, `story-elements` is a an array of json objects, but you trying to extract array as a string (`(parsedJson\"cards"\"story-elements").extract[String]`).

You can create case class representing on story (like `case class Story(description: String, pageUrl: String, ...)`) and then instead of `extract[String]`, try `extract[List[Story]]` or `extract[Array[Story]]`
If you need just one piece of data from story (e.g. descrition), then you can use xpath-like syntax to get that and then extract `List[String]`